# Tkinter notification board with messages from socket - Weird behaviour

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, tkinter

I'm using this forum for some time, but this is the first time that I ask a question, since I haven't been able to find a good way around my difficulties, and because I hope this question will be useful to other people too.

I am implementing a simple notification board, i.e. a window where messages coming from a socket connection are displayed. This board prints in red the last message received and in blue the old ones, up to ten. When a message sent by the client is 'Q', the connection terminates and the notification board is destroyed.

I am using Tkinter, threading and sockets, but the behaviour is not smooth (it takes a while to refresh the notification board). I can think of a few problems: the thread handling the connection is not closed; the update of the window is performed by destroying and recreating the toplevel. Unfortunately I can't understand if these issues are the source of the problem.

Here is the code for the client, a very simple one:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket

HOST = ''           # Symbolic name meaning the local host
PORT = 24073        # Arbitrary non-privileged port

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST,PORT))

while True:
    message = raw_input('Enter your command (Q=quit): ')
    s.send(message)
    reply = s.recv(1024)
    if reply=='Q':
        print 'Request to disconnect was received.'
        break
    else :
        print reply
s.close()
```

And here is the server. The server has implemented a class that handles the notification board characteristics, a thread for the socket connection and finally the main part with the `mainloop()`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket
import threading

from Tkinter import *
from datetime import datetime

### Class definition

class NoticationsBoard() :

    def __init__(self, title):
        self.messages = []
        self.toplevel = None
        self.title = title
        self.backgroundColor = 'black'
        self.textColor = 'blue'
        self.textColorFirst = 'red'
        self.boardSize = '200x250+0+0'
        self.listsize = 10

    def createBoard(self):
        self.toplevel = Toplevel()
        self.toplevel.title(self.title)
        self.toplevel.configure(background='black')
        self.toplevel.geometry(self.boardSize)

    def publish(self, message):
        self.addToList(message)
        self.displayList()

    def addToList(self, msg):
        if len(self.messages) == self.listsize:
            self.messages.pop(0)
        timestamp = datetime.utcnow().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
        newMessage = (msg, timestamp)
        self.messages.append(newMessage)

    def displayList(self):
        # Destroy and create the window (is it really necessary?)
        if self.toplevel is not None :
            self.toplevel.destroy()
        self.createBoard()
        # create labels for all the messages in the list
        index = 1
        for m, t in self.messages :
            color = self.textColor
            if index == len(self.messages) :
                color = self.textColorFirst
            label = Label(self.toplevel, text=m, height=0, width=100, fg=color, anchor=W)
            label.grid(row=0,column=1)
            label.configure(background=self.backgroundColor)
            label.pack(side='bottom')
            index = index +1

####### Run

def receiveMessages(newsboard) :
    print '===== Inside receiveMessages ======'
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    print 'Socket created'
    try:
        s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    except socket.error , msg:
        print 'Bind failed. Error code: ' + str(msg[0]) + 'Error message: ' + msg[1]
        sys.exit()
    print 'Socket bind complete'
    s.listen(1)
    print 'Socket now listening on port', PORT
    # Accept the connection once
    (conn, addr) = s.accept()
    print 'Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1])
    stored_data = ''
    while True:
        # RECEIVE DATA
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        # PROCESS DATA
        if data == 'Q' :
            print 'Client wants to disconnect.'
            reply = 'Q'
            conn.send(reply)
            break
        else :
            print data
            newsboard.publish(data)
            reply = 'Message received:' + data
            conn.send(reply)
    print 'Close connection.'
    conn.close()
    board.destroy()

HOST = ''   # Symbolic name meaning the local host
PORT = 24073    # Arbitrary non-privileged port

app = Tk()
app.title("GUI main")

board = NoticationsBoard('Notifications')    

t = threading.Thread(target=receiveMessages, args = (board,))
t.start()

app.update()    # Not sure what it does and if it is necessary
app.mainloop()
```

I am using Python 2.7.5.

Finally, but this is something minor, I was trying to display the timestamp of each message on the left of the message itself, in a different color. It seems to me that it is not possible to have text of different colours on the same label, so I had created other labels in the `for` loop with the timestamps. I tried to display the timestamp and message labels one next to the others using `.grid(column=0)` and `.grid(column=1)`, but they were not one next to the other but one below the other, and I haven't figured out why.

As you understood, I am not a skilled programmer, and definitely a newbie with Python...

Thanks in advance to whom will give me some advice, and I hope this question will be useful to many people.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/16745507/291641. Calling UI methods from a different thread is likely to cause problems. As suggested, use a queue and poll the queue from the UI thread should solve the issues. Or use Twisted to make the whole run with 1 thread in an event oriented manner.

Comment: Thank you patthoyts for your suggestions. I am not sure to have understood how I can avoid calling UI methods from the threaded `receiveMessages()` function. I looked at the question you linked but I struggle to see where the `queue` and the `poll` would need to be added.
As for Twisted, an event oriented tool could be a good idea but I am wondering if that would be excessive given the simplicity of the task that theoretically this code should perform. Would an event driven implementation simplify the whole structure in your opinion?

Comment: Quick update: I am rewriting the code starting from the recipe written by Jacob Hallén (http://code.activestate.com/recipes/82965-threads-tkinter-and-asynchronous-io/). As soon as I get it working, I will upload my working solution (which probably won't be the best possible, but yet!).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems like I found a solution by taking parts of other people's questions, suggestions, and code. There are few differences in the appearance maybe.
In the GUI, the most notable one is that I preload all the Labels and then I just modify the text.
In the threading part, well, that's completely changed. Please see below.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python

try:
    import Tkinter
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as Tkinter
import time
import threading
import random
import Queue
import socket
import sys
from datetime import datetime

class GuiPart:
    def __init__(self, master, queue):
        self.queue = queue
        # GUI stuff
        self.labelArray = []
        self.messages = []
        # Set up the GUI
        self.master = master
        self.backgroundColor = 'black'
        self.listsize = 10
        master.config(bg=self.backgroundColor)
        self.board = Tkinter.LabelFrame(self.master, text='Notification Board',     bg='Black', fg='Yellow', labelanchor='n', width=170)
        self.initLabels()
        self.board.pack()

    def initLabels(self) :
        self.textColorTime = 'cyan'
        self.textColorMessage = 'orange'
        colorTime = 'blue'
        colorMessage = 'red'
        for i in range(0,self.listsize):
            la = Tkinter.Label(self.board, height=0, width=10, bg=self.backgroundColor, fg=colorTime, anchor=Tkinter.W)
            lb = Tkinter.Label(self.board, height=0, width=160, bg=self.backgroundColor, fg=colorMessage)
            la.grid(row=i,column=0, sticky=Tkinter.W)
            lb.grid(row=i,column=1, sticky=Tkinter.W)
            self.labelArray.append((la, lb))
            colorTime = self.textColorTime
            colorMessage = self.textColorMessage
            self.initList()
        self.displayList()

    def initList(self):
        for i in range(0, self.listsize):
            t = ''
            m = ''
            self.messages.append((t,m))

    def processIncoming(self):
        while self.queue.qsize():
            try:
                msg = self.queue.get(0)
                self.processMessage(msg)
            except Queue.Empty:
                pass

    def processMessage(self, message):
        timestamp = datetime.utcnow().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
        self.publish(timestamp, message)

    def publish(self, msg1, msg2):
        self.addToList(msg1, msg2)
        self.displayList()

    def addToList(self, msg1, msg2):
        if len(self.messages) == self.listsize:
            self.messages.pop(0)
        if (msg1 == None):
            msg1 = datetime.utcnow().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
        newMessage = (msg1, msg2)
        self.messages.append(newMessage)

    def displayList(self):
        index = self.listsize -1
        for t, m in self.messages :
            la, lb = self.labelArray[index]
            la.config(text=t)
            lb.config(text=m)
            index = index -1

    def destroy(self):
        self.master.destroy()

class ThreadedClient:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        # Create the queue
        self.queue = Queue.Queue()
        # Define connection parameters
        self.conn = None
        self.bindError = False
        # Set up the GUI part
        self.gui = GuiPart(master, self.queue)
        # Set up the thread to do asynchronous I/O
        self.running = True
        self.commThread = threading.Thread(target=self.workerThreadReceive)
        self.commThread.daemon = True
        self.commThread.start()
        # Start the periodic call in the GUI to check if the queue contains anything
        self.periodicCall()

    def periodicCall(self):
        if not self.running:
            self.killApplication()
        else :
            self.gui.processIncoming()
            self.master.after(100, self.periodicCall)

    def workerThreadReceive(self):
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        try :
            s.bind((HOST, PORT))
        except socket.error as msg :
            print 'Bind failed. Error code: ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Error message: ' + str(msg[1])
            self.running = False
            self.bindError = True
            return
        s.listen(1)
        (self.conn, self.addr) = s.accept()
        while self.running :
            data = self.conn.recv(1024)
            if data == 'Q' :
                self.conn.sendall('Q')
                self.running = False
            else :
                self.queue.put(data)
                reply = 'ACK'
                self.conn.sendall(reply)
        if self.conn is not None:
            self.conn.close()

    def killApplication(self):
        self.running = False
        if (self.conn is None) and (not self.bindError) :
            sfake = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            sfake.connect((HOST,PORT))
            sfake.sendall('Q')
            sfake.close()
        self.gui.destroy()
        sys.exit()


HOST = ''       # Symbolic name meaning the local host
PORT = 24073    # Arbitrary non-privileged port

root = Tkinter.Tk()

client = ThreadedClient(root)

root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", client.killApplication)
root.mainloop()
```

The client is the same as in the question.

I am not sure my code is the most elegant one (ok, let's say it... it is not!), but it seems to do the job. Nevertheless, I would like to get your feedback about it, because I am sure that I have overlooked many issues and that things could have done in an easier way. :)