# How to cancel a running script in tkinter

Tags: tkinter

I'm trying to make an aplication for my Raspberry Pi. An intervalometer for photographic purposes. I have made a GUI with tkinter but I can't found the way to cancel a running script , because all the buttons are blocked when the script is running.
May be it's no possible because my scripts contains loops ( for i in range()...
I have been trying the ".after" method but this one just stop the script without cancelling it.
Thanks in advence for your help

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read how to ask; you should provide a minimal complete verifiable example of your script

Comment: You've asked this same question on the Raspberry Pi forums.
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=174563&p=1114532#p1114532

If you add your code on the forums inside [code][/code] tags I can help you.

Comment: I'm very beginner and I don't know exactly how to insert code... Thanks

Comment: I start to see the light.... This is the situation now, not the best , but I can stop and reset the START script:

Comment: Sorry I want to add CODE to this question but I don't know how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use threading or multiprocess. You can refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16745507/tkinter-how-to-use-threads-to-preventing-main-event-loop-from-freezing) to find out more about it. Also, if you just want to stop the script from running, you can either send SIGKILL signal to your program from Terminal (the command is `killall Python -9`) or add a button in your program that calls `sys.exit()`

Comment: @josepraspi You can choose to accept the answers that you found helpful. Just click on the check symbol (✓) on the left side of each answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
from Tkinter import *
```

class Example:

```
def __init__(self, master):

    self.etfilm = Label(root,width=12, font=('arial narrow', 14, 'normal'),fg="white", bg="green")
    self.etfilm.grid(row=0, column=0,columnspan=1, padx=3, pady=2, sticky=NSEW)
    self.etstatus = Label(root,width=12, font=('arial narrow', 14, 'normal'),bg="yellow")
    self.etstatus.grid(row=0, column=1,columnspan=1, padx=3, pady=2, sticky=NSEW)
    self.textBox = Text(root,height= 1,width=2, relief=SUNKEN, font=('arial', 18, 'normal'),)
    self.textBox.grid(row=0, column=2, ipadx=13, padx=0, sticky=NSEW)
    self.botshoot = Button(root, width=18, font=('arial narrow', 30, 'normal'), text="START ", activebackground="#00dfdf")
    self.botshoot.grid(row=4, rowspan=2, column=0,columnspan=3,ipady=15,pady=1, sticky=NSEW)
    self.botshoot.configure(command=self.start)
    self.botkam = Button(root,width=10, font=('arial', 24, 'normal'), text="VIDEO SETTINGS", activebackground="#00dfdf")
    self.botkam.grid(row=6, rowspan=3, column=0,columnspan=2, pady=1, sticky=NSEW)
    self.botkamStop = Button(root,width=3, font=('arial', 24, 'normal'), text="STOP", activebackground="#00dfdf")
    self.botkamStop.grid(row=6, rowspan=3, column=2, pady=1, sticky=NSEW)
    self.botSelf = Button(root,width=10, font=('arial', 24, 'normal'), text="ACTIVATE SELFTIMER", activebackground="#00dfdf")
    self.botSelf.grid(row=9, rowspan=3, column=0,columnspan=2, pady=1, sticky=NSEW)
    self.botSelf1 = Button(root,width=3, font=('arial', 24, 'normal'), text="STOP", activebackground="#00dfdf")
    self.botSelf1.grid(row=9, rowspan=3, column=2, pady=1, sticky=NSEW)       
    self.botConf = Button(root,heigh=2, font=('arial', 18, 'normal'), text="CONFIGURE", activebackground="red")
    self.botConf.grid(row=12, rowspan=3, column=0,columnspan=1, pady=1, sticky=NSEW)
    self.botStop = Button(root,heigh=2, font=('arial', 18, 'normal'), text="STOP/RESET", activebackground="red")
    self.botStop.grid(row=12, rowspan=3, column=1,columnspan=2, pady=1, sticky=NSEW)
    self.botStop.configure(state=DISABLED,command=self.stop)

def start(self):
    self.count = 0
    self.cancel_id = None
    self.botConf.configure(state=DISABLED)
    self.botshoot.configure(state=DISABLED)
    self.botStop.configure(state=NORMAL)
    self.counter()

def counter(self):
    self.textBox.delete("1.0", END)
    if self.count < 10:
        self.count += 1
        self.textBox.insert(END, str(self.count)+'\n\n')
        self.cancel_id = self.textBox.after(1000, self.counter)

        root.update_idletasks()
        print(self.count)
def stop(self):
    if self.cancel_id is not None:
        self.textBox.after_cancel(self.cancel_id)
        self.cancel_id = None
        self.textBox.insert(END, 0)
        self.textBox.delete("1.0", END)
        self.botConf.configure(state=NORMAL)
        self.botshoot.configure(state=NORMAL)
```

root=Tk()
Example(root)
root.mainloop()