# Repeat a function after showing a message box every n seconds

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, setinterval

I want to set a function to repeat again again after the message box is shown.
A short example of code is shown below that what i exactly want to do

```
def setInterval(func,time,args):
    e = threading.Event()
    while not e.wait(time):
        func(args)

def foo(data):
    print data
    aa("what")
def aa(a):
    print(a)

tkMessageBox.showinfo("Regret","nope")

setInterval(foo,5,"fsrty")
```

All things are okay but the problem is only that once the messgae box is shown its give "not responding error".Anyone please help to find out the solution

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use the .after method since threading never work well this tkinter and nor does a while loop.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import TkMessageBox

def setInterval(func,time,args):
        func(args)
        root.after(time, setInterval(func, time, args))
root.tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
def foo(data):
    print data
    aa("what")
def aa(a):
    print(a)

tkMessageBox.showinfo("Regret","nope")
setInterval(foo, 5, "fsrty")
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Threading and Tk don't mix well, as they violate the Tcl/Tk threading model of using Tk just from *one thread* and your code doesnt work, because you occupied the main (one and only) thread!

While your print-functions keeps printing - GUI is unresponsible because of that and you can check it easily with another `print` in your code:

```
>>> print('**** Active threads: %d ****' % threading.active_count())
**** Active threads: 1 ****
```

So what you really need is just create another one!

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import messagebox as msgbox
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk
    import TkMessageBox as msgbox

import threading


def setInterval(func,time,args):
    e = threading.Event()
    while not e.wait(time):
        print('**** Active threads: %d ****' % threading.active_count())
        func(args)


def foo(data):
    print(data)
    aa("what")


def aa(a):
    print(a)


root = tk.Tk()

print('**** Active threads: %d ****' % threading.active_count())
thread = threading.Thread(target=setInterval, args=(foo, 5, "fsrty"))
msgbox.showinfo("Regret", "nope")
thread.start()

root.mainloop()
```

But here's another problem - threads keep running even after your close GUI (when you escaped `mainloop`)! So if you trying to achieve something simple - [`.after()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method) is an option (quick and small alternative).

But if you stubborny or really need this - create (override) a custom subclass of the thread object, it's gives you more flexibility to control your flow!

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import messagebox as msgbox
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk
    import TkMessageBox as msgbox

import threading


class Thread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Thread, self).__init__()
        self.running = False
        self.function_to_execute = None
        self._stop = threading.Event()

    def start_thread(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
        self.function_to_execute = (func, args, kwargs)
        self.running = True
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        print('### STARTED ###')
        while self.running:
            try:
                print('### RUNNING ###')
                function, args, kwargs = self.function_to_execute
                function(*args, **kwargs)
            except:
                self.stop()

    def stop(self):
        print('### STOPPING ###')
        self.running = False
        self._stop.set()


def setInterval(func, time, args):
    e = threading.Event()

    e.wait(time)
    print('**** Active threads: %d ****' % threading.active_count())
    func(args)


def foo(data):
    print(data)
    aa('what')


def aa(a):
    print(a)


def clear():
    thread.stop()

    while True:
        try:
            thread.is_alive()
        except TypeError:
            root.destroy()
            print('### STOPPED ###')
            print('**** Active threads: %d ****' % threading.active_count())
            break


root = tk.Tk()

thread = Thread()
print('**** Active threads: %d ****' % threading.active_count())
msgbox.showinfo("Regret", "nope")
thread.start_thread(setInterval, foo, 5, 'fsrty')
root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', clear)

root.mainloop()
```

As you see - things are getting more complicated when we trying to clear out before exiting, but it's works!

**Conclusion:**

- For simple things - `.after()` is a good option!
- For complicated and long-executed things - `threading` is your choise!

**Links:**

- [`after()` method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method)
- [Tkinter: How to use threads to preventing main event loop from “freezing”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16745507/tkinter-how-to-use-threads-to-preventing-main-event-loop-from-freezing)
- [Tkinter and Threads](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-threads.htm)
- Also, when things getting complicated: [Best way to structure a tkinter application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466561/best-way-to-structure-a-tkinter-application)

Comment: Thanx a lot it will help me lot