# Is it possible to keep a tkinter window open whilst running code behind it?

Tags: python, tkinter

The idea is that it searches for a particular file while keeping a loading screen up then closes when the search is complete. This is my current code and it will not continue until the window is closed.

```
from tkinter import *
import os

def check():
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk ("C:\\Users\\"):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith("Details.txt"):
                fileLocation=(os.path.join(root, file))
                print(fileLocation)
                loading.destroy()

            else:
                createFile=open("Details.txt", "w")
                createFile.close()
                loading.destroy()
loading = Tk()
text = Label(loading, text="Loading...")
text.pack()
loading.mainloop()
check()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate [tkinter-how-to-use-threads-to-preventing-main-event-loop-from-freezing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16745507/tkinter-how-to-use-threads-to-preventing-main-event-loop-from-freezing/16747734#16747734)

Comment: I think what would make most sense is to add the check as part of what your tkinter process will do (rather than just show a load screen).

Comment: Along the lines of what @stovfl is getting at, you could use multi-threading and run the code that does the searching at the same time as the GUI's `mainloop()` is executing (as long as the code doing the search doesn't make any `tkinter` calls itself).

Comment: *it will not continue until the window is closed.*: This is because `.mainloop()` is **blocking**. to mean, all after, are executed on return from `.mainloop()` which is your *window*.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how it could be done by making the file searching function run in a separate thread, as I suggested in a comment. It uses a `Threading.Event` to communicate between the main thread which is running the tkiner GUI, and the thread doing the searching. I also fixed the search function so it properly creates the file when it wasn't found at end.

```
import os
import sys
import tkinter as tk
from threading import Event, Thread

EVENT_TIMEOUT = .01  # A very short timeout - seconds.
POLLING_DELAY = 1000  # How often to check search status - millisecs.


def file_search(event):
    search_folder = r"C:\Users"
    target = "Details.txt"
    found = False

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(search_folder):
        for filename in files:
            if filename.endswith(target):  # "if filename == target" would work fine here.
                fileLocation = os.path.join(root, filename)
                print(fileLocation, "file found")
                found = True
                break
        if found:
            break  # Quit looking.

    if not found:
        createFile = open(target, "w")  # Creates empty file in cwd.
        createFile.close()
        fileLocation = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), target)
        print(fileLocation, "file created")

    event.set()  # Signal search has completed.


def check_status(parent, event):
    event_is_set = event.wait(EVENT_TIMEOUT)
    if event_is_set:  # Done searching?
        parent.destroy()
        sys.exit()
    else:  # Continue polling.
        parent.after(POLLING_DELAY, check_status, parent, event)


parent = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Label(parent, text="Loading...")
text.pack()
event = Event()
thread = Thread(target=file_search, args=(event,))
check_status(parent, event)  # Starts the polling of search status.
thread.start()
parent.mainloop()
```