# Function to check distance using ultrasonic sensor freezes tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using trying to use python with an ultrasonic sensor to measure distance, and then update a tkinter label with the distance value every second. However, I'm having problems; it will run for a while, anything from a couple of seconds up to a few minutes, then freeze.

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO_TRIGGER_X = 4
GPIO_ECHO_X = 27
GPIO.setup(GPIO_TRIGGER_X, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(GPIO_ECHO_X, GPIO.IN)

def distanceX():

    GPIO.output(GPIO_TRIGGER_X, True)
    time.sleep(0.0001)
    GPIO.output(GPIO_TRIGGER_X, False)

    StartTime = time.time()
    StopTime = time.time()

    while GPIO.input(GPIO_ECHO_X) == 0:
        StartTime = time.time()

    while GPIO.input(GPIO_ECHO_X) == 1:
        StopTime = time.time()

    TimeElapsed = StopTime - StartTime
    distance = (TimeElapsed * 34300) / 2

    return distance

def updateDistance():
        dX = distanceX()
        print(dX)
        lengthValue.configure(text=dX)
        root.after(1000, updateDistance)

root = Tk()

root.geometry("200x100")
root.tk_setPalette(background="white", foreground="black")

lengthName = Label(root, text = "Length:")
lengthValue = Label(root, text="start")

lengthName.grid(row=1, column=1)
lengthValue.grid(row=1, column=2)

updateDistance() 
root.mainloop()
```

I have tried running `distanceX()` alone in a separate script just printing out the values, that works fine. I've also tried the running the script without `distanceX()` like this:

```
dX = 0

def updateDistance():
        global dX
        print(dX)
        lengthValue.configure(text=dX)
        dX += 1
        root.after(1000, updateDistance)
```

..and that also works fine.

Any ideas? 
Apologies in advance if I've left any needed info out, this is my first go at python and tkinter...

Comment: Try using `threading.Thread()`.

Comment: Do not use sleep in tkinter. `sleep()` will block the mainloop. That said if you use threading you can use sleep in a separate thread. You need to take care on how you build your loops because tkinter runs in a single thread.

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter is single threaded. Your while loop in function `distanceX` blocks the main thread until it receives a True value and continues with the rest of the function. That's why you are experiencing freezes.

Try run the below:

```
from tkinter import *
import time

root = Tk()
flag = True

def something():
    global flag
    while flag:
        print ("Hello World")
        time.sleep(1)

def set_flag():
    global flag
    flag = False

something()
root.after(2000,set_flag)
root.mainloop()
```

And you will see your Tk window won't even pop up due to While loop blocking the main thread.

To solve this, you need to thread your `distanceX()` function. Something like:

```
from tkinter import *
import threading, time

root = Tk()
flag = True

def something():
    global flag
    while flag:
        print ("Hello world")
        time.sleep(1)

def set_flag():
    global flag
    flag = False

t = threading.Thread(target=something)
t.start()
root.after(2000,set_flag)
root.mainloop()
```

You can read more about threading in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16745507/tkinter-how-to-use-threads-to-preventing-main-event-loop-from-freezing).

Comment: Using `threading.Event` object instead of global `flag` is more preferable.

Comment: I added `lengthValue.configure(text=distance)` to `distanceX()` and threaded the function by adding `t = threading.Thread(target=distanceX)` and
`t.start()` as you suggested. I also added a button to the GUI that will simply print "All good" just so I could have a sure way of checking if the GUI was still responsive. When I run this, the label will update fine at first but then stop updating after a while (like before), but the button prints "All good" as it's supposed to...

Comment: Because your function only got executed once in the thread. You will need to wrap your `distanceX()` inside a loop function and thread the loop.

Comment: I did, I included `while True` to the beginning of `distanceX()`. It works perfectly fine, I can see the label updating with the correct values, but it will suddenly stop updating, testrun I just did took 15 min before it stopped updating. But like I said, the main thread & GUI seems to be fine also after that point, the button I added that prints "All good" works fine even then.

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow so I'll check first; am I ok to add the full, rewritten code as an answer so I can show all the changes?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was in fact the two `while` loops in `distanceX()`. Added a timeout to both and all is well. Working code:

```
from tkinter import *
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import threading, time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO_TRIGGER_X = 4
GPIO_ECHO_X = 27
GPIO.setup(GPIO_TRIGGER_X, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(GPIO_ECHO_X, GPIO.IN)

def distanceX():

    while True:
         timeout = time.time() + 0.1
         GPIO.output(GPIO_TRIGGER_X, True)
         time.sleep(0.0001)
         GPIO.output(GPIO_TRIGGER_X, False)

         StartTime = time.time()
         StopTime = time.time()

         while GPIO.input(GPIO_ECHO_X) == 0:
            StartTime = time.time()
            if time.time() > timeout:
                break

         while GPIO.input(GPIO_ECHO_X) == 1:
            StopTime = time.time()
            if time.time() > timeout:
                break

         TimeElapsed = StopTime - StartTime
         distance = (TimeElapsed * 34300) / 2

         print(distance)
         lengthValue.configure(text=distance)

         time.sleep(1)

def check():
    print("All good")


root = Tk()

root.geometry("200x100")
root.tk_setPalette(background="white", foreground="black")

lengthName = Label(root, text = "Length:")
lengthValue = Label(root, text="start")
button = Button(root, text="Check", command=check)

lengthName.grid(row=1, column=1)
lengthValue.grid(row=1, column=2)
button.grid(row=2, column=1)

t1 = threading.Thread(target=distanceX)
t1.start()
root.mainloop()
```