# TkInter: how to wait until callback from after method has completed

Tags: python, tkinter

When using the Tkinter .after method, the code continues passed without waiting for the callback to complete.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import time
from datetime import datetime

global i
i = 0
global j
j = 0

def SomeFunction():
    global i
    for num in range(10):
        i+=1
        x = barVar.get()
        barVar.set(x+5)
        histrun_mainWindow.update()
        time.sleep(2)

def SecondFunction():
    global j
    for num in range(10):
        j+=1
        x = barVar.get()
        barVar.set(x+5)
        histrun_mainWindow.update()
        time.sleep(2)

def Load(run_date):
    histrun_mainWindow.after(50, SomeFunction)
    histrun_mainWindow.after(50, SecondFunction)
    global i, j 
    print 'Number is :', i + j

histrun_mainWindow = tk.Tk()
run_date = datetime.today().date()
barVar = tk.DoubleVar()
barVar.set(0)
bar = ttk.Progressbar(histrun_mainWindow, length=200, style='black.Horizontal.TProgressbar', variable=barVar, mode='determinate')
bar.grid(row=1, column=0)
button= tk.Button(histrun_mainWindow, text='Run for this date ' + str(run_date), command=lambda:Load(run_date))
button.grid(row=0, column=0)
histrun_mainWindow.mainloop()
```

This example shows what is happening. The .after() calls the Load() function but doesn't wait for Load() to complete, it goes straight on to the next line.

I want i to print as 10 but because the .after() doesn't wait for Load() to finish it's additions, i prints as 0

The progress bar continues to update so I know that Load was called as it continues in the background after i is printed

Comment: Why do you need to delay the call to `SomeFunction()` with `after()`- if you call it directly, it will behave as you wish.

Comment: In my real code the function `Load()` contains multiple `after()` methods to gather data. Each depends on the previous function having completed so that they can use data it has called/calculated. I have added more detail to my example to clarify.

Comment: If I call the functions directly without `after()`, the progress bar doesn't update - the window freezes until all functions have completed. Maybe there is a better way to get this functionality?

Comment: @JK: *"a better way to get this functionality"*: Read [use threads to preventing main event loop from “freezing”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16747734/7414759).

Comment: @stovfl thank you for that link. I'm having difficulty understanding it though, I'm only used to very basic multithreading and I've never worked with classes before. Do I need to create a separate class for `SomeFunction()` and `SecondFunction()` and how do I call a class when calling a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Question:** the progress bar doesn't update - the window freezes until all functions have completed

Use a `Thread` to prevent `main loop` from **freezing**.
Your functions - `SomeFunction`, `SecondFunction` - may also in `global` namespace.
Then you have to pass `self.pbar` as paramter, e.g. `SomeFunction(pbar): ... f(self.pbar)`.

---

> **Note**:
>   You see a `RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop`
>   **if you `.destroy()` the `App()` window while the `Thread` is running**!

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        btn = tk.Button(self, text='Run', 
                              command=lambda :threading.Thread(target=self.Load).start())
        btn.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.pbar = ttk.Progressbar(self, maximum=2 *(5 * 5), mode='determinate')
        self.pbar.grid(row=1, column=0)

    def SomeFunction(self):
        for num in range(5):
            print('SomeFunction({})'.format(num))
            self.pbar['value'] += 5
            time.sleep(1)
        return num

    def SecondFunction(self):
        for num in range(5):
            print('SecondFunction({})'.format(num))
            self.pbar['value'] += 5
            time.sleep(1)
        return num

    def Load(self):
        number = 0
        for f in [self.SomeFunction, self.SecondFunction]:
            number += f()
        print('Number is :{}'.format(number))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    App().mainloop()
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> SomeFunction(0)
> SomeFunction(1)
> SomeFunction(2)
> SomeFunction(3)
> SomeFunction(4)   
> SecondFunction(0)
> SecondFunction(1)
> SecondFunction(2)
> SecondFunction(3)
> SecondFunction(4)
> Number is :8
> ```

***Tested with Python: 3.5***
*)*Could not test with Python 2.7*

Comment: That's perfect thanks very much for your help! I was able to use this and passing the `self.pbar` parameter opens up more uses when threading