# How to make tkinter wait for a new thread to complete?

Tags: python, tkinter

How to make tkinter execution in function `fix()` wait till `label's` text get chnaged and then print `end`.

Current working: When I click the `sub` button, new thread gets created and `for` loop gets executed. After 10000000 loops, my label would change to `9999999`. But before my label changes, tkinter prints `end`.

I tried `t.join()`, but it freezes the GUI.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import threading

root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(text='vinoth')
label.pack()

def fix():
    a=0
    t = threading.Thread(target=count, args=(a,))
    t.start()
    #t.join()
    print('end')

def count(a):
        for i in range(0,10000000):
            a=i
        label['text'] = a

button = tk.Button(text='sub', command=fix)
button.pack()
dropdown = ttk.Combobox()
dropdown.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I will be replacing the line `print('end')` with many lines of code, tkinter multi threading does not support those. So I have to perform the work in new thread and come back to main thread. Please guide me how to put a pause in function `fix` till thread `t` completes.

Comment: You want something like this: [how to wait until callback has completed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55872876/7414759)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to be careful multithreading `tkinter` applications because the interface to tcl/tk doesn't doesn't support it. That means only the main thread can make calls to `tkinter` and its widgets.

That said, you can workaround the limitation by using the universal [`after()`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) method to schedule a function to run periodically and communicate with the thread, either through thread-safe mechanisms like a [`Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) or via global variables coupled with a [`Lock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#lock-objects) to control concurrent access to it or them.

Here's an example of using the latter to do what you're trying to accomplish:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import threading


POLLING_DELAY = 250  # ms
lock = threading.Lock()  # Lock for shared resources.
finished = False

root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(text='vinoth')
label.pack()

def fix():
    global finished

    with lock:
        finished = False
    t = threading.Thread(target=count)
    t.daemon = True
    root.after(POLLING_DELAY, check_status)  # Start polling.
    t.start()

def check_status():
    with lock:
        if not finished:
            root.after(POLLING_DELAY, check_status)  # Keep polling.
        else:
            print('end')

def count():
    global finished

    for i in range(10000000):
        a = i
    with lock:
        finished = True
        label['text'] = a


button = tk.Button(text='sub', command=fix)
button.pack()
dropdown = ttk.Combobox()
dropdown.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: That was beautiful! Can you please provide an example for Queue as well? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @User1493: If my answer solves your problem, please accept it. FYI, in the past I once posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53697547/355230) to a related question about waiting for thread completion that uses a `Queue`.

Comment: @martineau, thanks for your support. But the code you shared never prints `end`

Comment: How would the variable `finished` become `True`, when the `daemon thread` completes execution?

Comment: @user1404: The `count()` functions set it to `True` after the `for` loop. However I forgot to declare it `global` in a couple of functions that change its value, which is why it didn't print `end`—although it's a lame excuse, the reason is simply because I don't use globals much myself and simply forgot…

Comment: Yeah, found that sometime back. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I gave this a try by using `root.update()` function in a while loop. Not sure if this is a right away to do things! But posting the code anyway:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import threading

root = tk.Tk()

class test():

    def __init__(self):
        self.label = tk.Label(text='vicks')
        self.label.pack()
        button = tk.Button(text='sub', command=self.fix)
        button.pack()
        dropdown = ttk.Combobox()
        dropdown.pack()

    def fix(self):
        self.finished = False
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.count)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
        self.check_status()
        print('end')

    def check_status(self):
        while self.finished is False:  #keeps running until the variable finished becomes True
            root.update()

    def count(self):
        a=0
        for i in range(100000000):
            a = i
        self.label['text'] = a
        self.finished = True

c = test()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This looks very simple and on point. Thank you very much! Seems like there are a lot of ways to achieve things.