# Why does the code terminates after once the user asks query

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, speech-recognition, pyttsx

This is a code for a virtual assistant this code terminates after the user speaks once. I need this code to iterate till the user says exit. I tried using 'while True' after 'if **name** == "**main**":
    wishme()' it runs, but in that case it does not show the tkinter window. Can you help me please?
Here is my code

```
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr
import datetime
import wikipedia
import webbrowser
import os
import smtplib
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
```

## print(voices[0].id)

```
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[0].id)


def speak(audio):       
    e1 = Text(root)
    e1.grid(row=0, column=0)
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()
    t = Text(root)
    t.grid(row = 0, column = 0, 
        columnspan = 2, rowspan = 2, padx = 5, pady = 5) 
    t.insert(END, 'Genos says: '+ audio +'\n')



def wishme():
    hour = int(datetime.datetime.now().hour)
    if hour>=0 and hour<12:
        speak("Good Morning sir")

    elif hour>=12 and hour<18:
        speak("Good Afternoon sir")

    else:
        speak("Good Evening sir")    
    speak("I am Genos. How can I Serve you?")
    return

def takecommand():
    # it takes mic input from the user and return string output

    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening...")
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        audio = r.listen(source)

    try:
        print("Recognizing..")
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-in')
        print(f"user Said :{query}\n")

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

        print("Say that again please")
        return "None"
    t1 = Text(root)
    t1.grid(row = 0, column = 2, 
       columnspan = 2, rowspan = 2, padx = 5, pady = 5)  
    t1.insert(END, 'user says: '+query+'\n')
    return query

def sendEmail(to, content):
    server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.login('your email@gmail.com','password')
    server.sendmail('your email@gmail.com',to,content)
    server.close()
    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    wishme()
    #while True:
    if 1:
        query = takecommand().lower()


#Logic for executing task based query 
        if 'wikipedia' in query:
            speak('searching Wikipedia....')
            query = query.replace("wikpedia", "")
            results = wikipedia.summary(query, sentences=5)
            speak("According to wikipedia")
            print(results)
            speak(results)

        elif 'open youtube' in query:
             webbrowser.open("youtube.com")

        elif 'open google' in query:
             webbrowser.open("google.com")

        elif 'open stackoverflow' in query:
             webbrowser.open("stackoverflow.com")

        elif 'play music' in query:
            music_dir = 'D:\\SAHIL\\$ONGS_MJ'
            songs = os.listdir(music_dir)
            print(songs)
            os.startfile(os.path.join(music_dir, songs[0]))

        elif 'the time' in query:
            strTime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
            speak(f"Sir the time is {strTime}")

        elif 'open code' in query:
            codepath = "C:\\Users\\Sahil\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code Insiders\\Code 
- Insiders.exe"
        os.startfile(codepath)

    elif 'email to sahil' in query:
        try:
            speak("What should i say ?")
            content = takecommand()
            to = "your email11@gmail.com"
            sendEmail(to, content)
            speak("Email has been sent")
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            speak("Could nott send the email ")

    elif 'open mailbox' in query:
        webbrowser.open("gmail.com");

    elif 'exit' in query:

        exit()
```

root.mainloop()

Comment: I would think that you would call your tkinter after if main. and your "logic" to listen to commands would be running within your tkinter class rather than outside of it.

Comment: First you have to understand [Event-driven programming](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9343402/7414759) and [use threads to preventing main event loop from “freezing”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16747734/7414759)