# Use watchdog and tkinter to open a GUI dialog when file in watched directory changes

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, watchdog, python-watchdog

I am trying this now for almost 24 hours, but I just can't get it to work and am not finding examples/solutions suitable for my use-case..

What I am trying to do is:

- Watch a directory with watchdog on file changes
- on `on_modified` event open a tkinter GUI

Problem: `Main-Thread` issues with the `mainloop()` and I only find examples for scripts where the GUI is always rendered straight from the beginning ..

Error: **`WARNING: NSWindow drag regions should only be invalidated on the Main Thread!`**
or
`main thread is not in main loop tkinter`

Minimalist code example:

```
class PopupWindow:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)

        # code for input fields
        # ...

        self.frame.pack()

    def set_user_input(self):
        self.master.destroy()
        self.master.quit()


class MainClass(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Watching files in '/directory-to-be-watched' for changes...")

    def run(self):
        print("Starting script")

        root = tk.Tk()
        app = PopupWindow(root)
        # read input values ...
        root.mainloop()
        root.destroy()

    def on_modified(self, event):
        self.run()


event_handler = MainClass()
observer = Observer()
observer.schedule(event_handler, "/directory-to-be-watched", recursive=False)
observer.start()


try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(10)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    observer.stop()

observer.join()
```

**ANY help would be highly appreciated, thanks in advance!**

Comment: You have to run either `tkinter` **OR** the `Observer` in a **own** `Thread`.

Comment: @stovfl thanks for the reply! Could you roughly explain how I do that?

Comment: Follow this approach [use threads to preventing main event loop from “freezing”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16747734/7414759)