# Tkinter not responding while using online API

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I am making a desktop application in Python using Tkinter as my gui interface. 
I am facing a problem where when I am executing [Astrometry.net API](http://astrometry.net/doc/net/api.html) and in that I am using their [client.py](https://github.com/dstndstn/astrometry.net/blob/master/net/client/client.py). Once my frame is loaded, it has one Label named "status_label". the functions in the client file are executed in order as follows "Login=>myjobs=>upload".
Now when my code is interacting with the API, my gui interface goes Not responding. 
To check this I even used status_label to display which function is executing by changing text of status_label to the name of the function currently executing right before the function is called. Still, the label is not updated at the end and in the meanwhile the entire time when it interacts with online API, entire gui is Not-Responding.

How to avoid this problem and get the function name in the label?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter: How to use threads to preventing main event loop from "freezing"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16745507/tkinter-how-to-use-threads-to-preventing-main-event-loop-from-freezing)

Answer (score 0):

This propably happens because the Astronomy API is sharing a thread with Tkinter.You should have a different thread for the GUI (Tkinter) and a different for the Astronomy API.This way the Tkinter window will be responsive while your code uses the API.You can do the above with [multithreading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html).