# Making a "screen locker" with tkinter and schedule module

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, schedule

I've been wanting to create a program to "lock my screen" (don't ask why) from 11 PM to 6 AM. I recently found *schedule*, which allows me to run a function at a specific time. I tried to integrate it with tkinter, but something unexpected happened. Here is my code so far:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox, simpledialog
import schedule
import time

root = Tk()

def block_start():
    def provide_password_to_quit():
        user_result = simpledialog.askstring('Password', 'What is the password?')
        if user_result.lower() == 'password':
            root.destroy()

    global root
    root.geometry('1920x1080')
    root.overrideredirect(True) # makes root full-screen, which "locks" my monitor

    quit_button = Button(root, text="Quit", command=provide_password_to_quit)
    quit_button.pack()
    root.mainloop()

def block_off():
    global root
    root.overrideredirect(False) # "unlocks" my monitor


schedule.every().day.at("23:00").do(block_start) # creates full-screened window at 11 PM
schedule.every().day.at("06:00").do(block_off) # destroys full-screened window at 6 AM


while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

When I run this, it creates the full-screened window, but when trying to unlock my monitor at 6:00, it doesn't do anything, and once I close the full-screen, it *then* decides to run and raise `_tkinter.TclError` (because I destroyed root). Is there any way to work around this? I tried putting it in threads, but tkinter doesn't allow you to run GUIs not in the main thread.

Comment: But now I have to ask why...

Comment: hehe, my brother keeps using the computer a lot, so I wanted to make a program for him to stop using it

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16745507/tkinter-how-to-use-threads-to-preventing-main-event-loop-from-freezing), it might help.