# Discord.py: Trying to send custom messages via my bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, discord.py

Recently I have been into making of a bot and have done a lot but just a while ago I got into this error which is not really getting fixed by me. So I thought I could ask you for some help.

#### Context:

For the current situation my bot is to send a custom message which I send my self. For this I have created a **tkinter** window in which I have a `Text` widget and a `Button`. I enter the message I want to send inside the `Text` widget and then I click on the `Button` to send the message. The bot has to send that message as if **it** is sending it.

#### Error:

The script works just fine but whenever I click the button to send the text. It shows me the error mentioned below:

```
C:\Users\Bhavyadeep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py:1421: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'custom_message.<locals>.cm_send' was never awaited
  self.tk.mainloop(n)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

I tried several things myself but none seemed to work.

### Code:

Here is the code which relates to this issue:

```
@NucleoTech.command()
async def custom_message(ctx):
    if ctx.author.id == myid:
        confirm_embed = discord.Embed(title='Custom Message Window Opened!', description='Hey Bhavyadeep! I have opened the custom message window now. You can see it is visible to you now.', color=0x4fff4d)
        confirm_embed.set_footer(text=ctx.author)
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=confirm_embed)
        cm_window = Tk()

        cm_window.geometry('300x300')
        cm_window.resizable(False, False)

        cm_text = Text(cm_window, height=15, width=36)
        cm_text.place(x=2.75, y=1)

        async def cm_send():
            text = cm_text.get(1.0, 'end')
            sendcm_embed = discord.Embed(title='Custom Message!', desciption=f'{text}')
            sendcm_embed.set_author(name='NucleoBot')
            sendcm_embed.set_footer(text=ctx.author)
            await ctx.channel.send(embed=sendcm_embed)
            await asyncio.sleep(2)
            text.delete(1.0, 'end')

        cm_send_button = Button(cm_window, text='Send', command=cm_send, width=20, height=2)
        cm_send_button.place(x=2, y=250)

        cm_window.mainloop()

    if ctx.author.id != myid:
        errorperm_embed = discord.Embed(title='Access Denied!', description='This command is `OWNER` only. You are not allowed to use this. Try not to execute it another time.', color=0xFF0000)
        errorperm_embed.set_footer(text=ctx.author)
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=errorperm_embed)
```

---

If you still need the whole code you can ask me for it anytime. I would send it. :)

Thank You! :)

Comment: I would look at threading. Keep tkinter in the main thread (because it is not thread safe) and run the bot in another.

Comment: @Henry I appreciate your help but I didn't get what you meant. You want me to run this window in another file then import it in the main file with Bot's run code?

Comment: [Something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16745507/tkinter-how-to-use-threads-to-preventing-main-event-loop-from-freezing) may help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of Tkinter's problem. As @henry said it's not thread safe, that is, it runs **Tkinter** in a different ***processor core*** than your bot, and when the Bot tries to access the Text from the Text Widget, it is not able to get it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to change:

```
text.delete(1.0, 'end')
```

Into:

```
await text.delete(1.0, 'end')
```

Comment: This line can't be awaited. It would show an error.